# Googling in Selenium WebDriver, trying to verify result; result comes back as false when true

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to write a Selenium WebDriver test that navigates to Google, searches for something, and then verifies that Google has searched for what was typed in. However, the below code gives a "false" output, when I can see that it is true.

All of the code that I can find for this scenario seem to be pre-Google Instant, and I cannot make Instant stay turned off in FirefoxDriver. It should also be waiting for the bar with Web, Images, Video etc. to be clickable before checking anything; increasing the implicitlyWait value does not seem to have any effect on how the test plays out, or its final result. Switching between verifyTrue and assertTrue does not change the result.

I apologise if the answer is obvious, but I'm relatively new to Selenium WebDriver (and Java).

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class NavigateSearchVerify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(baseUrl);

        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Hello");
        query.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("top_nav")));

        Boolean assertTrue = driver.findElements(By.className("gbqfif")).contains("Hello");
        if (assertTrue == true) {
            System.out.print("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.print("No");
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On checking your question and code, this is what I understood :-

1. You want to open google
2. Type in "Hello" in the search box
3. Press enter
4. Verify whether "Hello" was entered in search box

`driver.findElements(By.className("gbqfif")).contains("Hello");` is not correct.

There are more than 4 elements with `className("gbqfif")`. So when you use `findElements()` a list of WebElements are returned. You are checking this list whether it contains 'Hello' string object. But the list contains WebElement objects.

Try the following code instead :
`driver.findElement(By.name("q")).getAttribute("value").contains("Hello");`

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

do you see it's true by debuggin it?

replace the lines when your **Boolean assertTrue** starts and try with this:

```
if(waitForTextToLoad(By.className("gbqfif"),"Hello")){
   System.out.println("Yes");
}else{
   System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

and put the following out of your main:

```
public boolean waitForTextToLoad(By by, String text){
        boolean wbeWaitFor = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(by, text));
        return wbeWaitFor;
    }
```